# subset unbalanced (hetero replicated replication) to complete or balance dataset in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset that unequal number of repetition. I want to subset a data by removing those entries that are incomplete (i.e. replication less than maximum). Just small example:

```
set.seed(123)
mydt <- data.frame (name= rep ( c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c(1,2,4,4, 3)), 
                   var1 = rnorm (14, 3,1), var2 = rnorm (14, 4,1))
 mydt
       name     var1     var2
1     A 2.439524 3.444159
2     B 2.769823 5.786913
3     B 4.558708 4.497850
4     C 3.070508 2.033383
5     C 3.129288 4.701356
6     C 4.715065 3.527209
7     C 3.460916 2.932176
8     D 1.734939 3.782025
9     D 2.313147 2.973996
10    D 2.554338 3.271109
11    D 4.224082 3.374961
12    E 3.359814 2.313307
13    E 3.400771 4.837787
14    E 3.110683 4.153373
```

summary(mydt)

```
name       var1            var2      
 A:1   Min.   :1.735   Min.   :2.033  
 B:2   1st Qu.:2.608   1st Qu.:3.048  
 C:4   Median :3.120   Median :3.486  
 D:4   Mean   :3.203   Mean   :3.688  
 E:3   3rd Qu.:3.446   3rd Qu.:4.412  
       Max.   :4.715   Max.   :5.787
```

I want to get rid of A, B, E from the data as they are incomplete. Thus expected output:

```
name     var1     var2
4     C 3.070508 2.033383
5     C 3.129288 4.701356
6     C 4.715065 3.527209
7     C 3.460916 2.932176
8     D 1.734939 3.782025
9     D 2.313147 2.973996
10    D 2.554338 3.271109
11    D 4.224082 3.374961
```

Please note the dataset is big, the following may not a option:

```
mydt[mydt$name == "C",]
mydt[mydt$name == "D", ]
```

Comment: Is completeness defined by 4 observations of the same name?

Comment: Yes, same name (are replicates) - 4 is the maximum replicates for the same name

Comment: The reason that it is not an option is because it is slow or because it would involve too much work?

Comment: @Dualinity I mean for example I need to write formula to select for example 1200 indivudals, I am not sure about speed, I do not know how to extract complete or incomplete cases

Comment: I think it would still be fine, though if you'd have to write it for many factors like A:Z then that would be a real drag...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydt, key = "name")
DT[, N := .N, by = key(DT)][N == max(N)]
#    name     var1     var2 N
# 1:    C 3.070508 2.033383 4
# 2:    C 3.129288 4.701356 4
# 3:    C 4.715065 3.527209 4
# 4:    C 3.460916 2.932176 4
# 5:    D 1.734939 3.782025 4
# 6:    D 2.313147 2.973996 4
# 7:    D 2.554338 3.271109 4
# 8:    D 4.224082 3.374961 4
```

`.N` gives you the number of cases per group, and using `data.table`'s option to *compound queries*, you can immediately subset based on whatever condition you want from this new variable.

There are several approaches in base R too, the most obvious of which is `table`:

```
with(mydt, mydt[name %in% names(which(table(name) == max(table(name)))), ])
```

Probably less common, but similar in approach to the `data.table` suggestion, is to use `ave()`:

```
counts <- with(mydt, as.numeric(ave(as.character(name), name, FUN = length)))
mydt[counts == max(counts), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple method that doesn't require creating an additional data structure

```
tabl <- table(mydt[,1])
toRemove <- names(which(tabl < max(tabl)))
mydt[!mydt[,1] %in% toRemove, ]


     #    name     var1     var2
     # 4     C 3.070508 2.033383
     # 5     C 3.129288 4.701356
     # 6     C 4.715065 3.527209
     # 7     C 3.460916 2.932176
     # 8     D 1.734939 3.782025
     # 9     D 2.313147 2.973996
     # 10    D 2.554338 3.271109
     # 11    D 4.224082 3.374961
```

---

#### As a single line:

```
 mydt[!mydt[,1] %in% names(which(table(mydt[,1]) < max(table(mydt[,1])))), ]
```